# How to put a pass retrieved from get into a parameter of a tag function?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have a code where I want to display a list of events, and the if the events are clicked on a modal will appear

```
 <script>
  function revealmodal(event) {
    console.log("Show modal", event);
    const ew = document.getElementById("eventWindow");
    $("#eventWindow").modal("show");
  }
</script>
<% for (let i= 0;i<event.length;i++){ %>
  <div>
    <div class="results" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick = 'revealmodal(<%event[i]%>)''> <%= event[i].eventname %> - <span style="color: rgb(145, 141, 141); font: 20px;"><%=event[i].eventdescription %></span>
      <div> <%=event[i].dateofevent%>: From <%=event[i].timestart%> to <%=event[i].timeend%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<%}%>
```

The problem is that I do not know how to pass "event" in this tag

```
<div class="results" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick = 'revealmodal(<%event[i]%>)''>
```

Any way to pass "event" through the function in the div tag?

Answer (score 0):

You need to approach this differently, much easier. 
Use the `data-` attribute model. 
This is then exposed on the object as [HTMLElement].dataset.[your attribute]

```js
// Here is where you use EJS to store events.
const myEvents = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Event 1',
  from: 'Sat',
  to: 'Sun'
},
{  
  id: 2,
  name: 'Event 2',
  from: 'Mon',
  to: 'Tue'
}];

const revealmodal = ({ dataset: { id }}) => {
    console.log("Show modal", id);
    const myEvent = myEvents.find(({ id: i }) => i == id);
    console.log(myEvent);
  };
```

```html
<div class="event" data-id="1" onclick="revealmodal(this);">1</div>
<div class="event" data-id="2" onclick="revealmodal(this);">2</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to pass id or this into my function I want to pass "event" which is an array which contains information of the event which I retrieved from a sql database

Comment: I understand, but you should store the `events` in an array and use id. Would you like me to flesh out above answer to demonstrate?

Comment: Yes I don't want to incorporate something that may drastically change how I'm writing my code

Comment: This method also only returns a single word instead of the entire string when you add it to the data-set

Comment: I added some data to demonstrate.